# Javascript remove all '|' in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I've got text from a title that can contain one or more `|` in it I'd like to use javascript to remove all instances of it.

I've tried

```
$('title').text().replace(/ |g /, ' ');
"What’s New On Netflix This Weekend: March 3–5 | Lifestyle"
```

Comment: `"What’s New On Netflix This Weekend: March 3–5 | Lifestyle".replace(/\|/g, ' ');`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your regex is invalid.

A valid one would look like that:

`/\|/g`

In normal JS:

```js
var text = "A | normal | text |";
var final = text.replace(/\|/g,"");
console.log(final);
```

---

Instead of using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a RegEx, you could just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on each occurence of `|` and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it.

<sub>Thanks to [@sschwei1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14764125/sschwei1) for the suggestion!</sub>

```js
const text = "A | normal | text |";
let final = text.split("|").join("");
console.log(final);
```

---

For more complex replacements, you could also do it with the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```js
var text = "A | normal | text |";

var final = text.split("").filter(function(c){ 
    return c != "|";
}).join("");

console.log(final);
```

---

Or with ES6:

```js
const text = "A | normal | text |";
let final = text.split("").filter(c => c !== "|").join("");
console.log(final);
```

---

**Update:** As of [ES12](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replaceall) you can now use [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
const text = "A | normal | text |";
let final = text.replaceAll("|", "");
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `.split("").filter(...).join("")` instead of just using `.split("|").join("")`, you would save the filter, as well as not having to split the whole string into every single character (I know this part of the answer is outdated, just curious)

Comment: @sschwei1 Nope, there isn't. Just didn't think of that when I wrote this answer ^^ (whew, been 4 years already). I included it into the answer now and mentioned you, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

RegEx was incorrect, it should look like this, with the `g` switch on the end, and the `|` escaped.

```js
var str = "What’s New On Netflix |This Weekend: March 3–5 | Lifestyle"

var replaced = str.replace(/\|/g, '');

console.log(replaced)
```